The homotopy set $[\mathbb{R}P^{n+1},S^n],\,n\ge3$
Question (courtesy of @BenSteffan): What is the homotopy set $[\mathbb{R}P^{n+1},S^n],\,n\ge 3$?
[This entire post takes place in the pointed category.] Note that there is, for any $n\ge1$, a cofiber sequence
$$S^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}\rightarrow S^{n+1}\rightarrow\Sigma\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow\dotsc.$$
This induces an exact sequence of pointed sets
$$\dotsc\rightarrow[\Sigma\mathbb{R}P^n,S^2]\rightarrow[S^{n+1},S^n]\rightarrow[\mathbb{R}P^{n+1},S^n]\rightarrow[\mathbb{R}P^n,S^n]\rightarrow[S^n,S^n],$$
where furthermore the group $[S^{n+1},S^n]=\pi_{n+1}(S^n)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts transitively on the fibers  of the restriction map $[\mathbb{R}P^{n+1},S^n]\rightarrow[\mathbb{R}P^n,S^n]$. Now, Hopf's Theorem states that $[-,S^n]$ corepresents $H^n(-;\mathbb{Z})$ on $\le n$-dimensional CW-complexes, so the latter map is identified with the pullback $H^n(\mathbb{R}P^n)\rightarrow H^n(S^n)=\mathbb{Z}$. Now, consider two cases:

If $n$ is odd, then $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is orientable, so the final map is $2\cdot\colon\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ (since $S^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^n$ is a double cover). In particular, this map is injective, so exactness yields that we have a surjection $\pi_{n+1}(S^n)\twoheadrightarrow[\mathbb{R}P^{n+1},S^n]$, so the homotopy set in question has $1$ or $2$ elements depending on whether the composite $\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}\rightarrow S^{n+1}\rightarrow S^n$ of the map collapsing $\mathbb{R}P^n$ and the $(n-2)$-fold suspension of the Hopf map $\eta\colon S^3\rightarrow S^2$ is non-trivial. It is not clear to me whether it is.

If $n$ is even, $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is non-orientable, so the final map is the null map $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, exactness yields that the restriction map $[\mathbb{R}P^{n+1},S^n]\twoheadrightarrow[\mathbb{R}P^n,S^n]=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is surjective. Furthermore, $\pi_{n+1}(S^n)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts transitively on its fibers, so the homotopy set in question has between $2$ and $4$ elements.


From this point, I cannot make any more progress. It's worth noting that the analogous question for $n=2$ can also be posed, in which case I know the answer. Namely, the projection $S^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^3$ induces a bijection $[\mathbb{R}P^3,S^2]\stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow}[S^2,S^2]=\mathbb{Z}$, which can be shown by constructing enough elements and using the above exact sequence. However, such an approach seems less feasible for $n\ge3$ since the analogous map $[\mathbb{R}P^{n+1},S^n]\rightarrow[S^{n+1},S^n]=\pi_{n+1}(S^n)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ now fails to detect the image of $[S^{n+1},S^n]\rightarrow[\mathbb{R}P^{n+1},S^n]$ since the composite $S^{n+1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}\rightarrow S^{n+1}$ is a degree $2$ map and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is $2$-torsion.

$\newcommand{\Sq}{\operatorname{Sq}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
$
A general theorem of Steenrod
The homotopy set $[X, S^n]$, where $X$ is a complex of dimension $n+1$, was described by Steenrod in the paper where he introduced the Steenrod operations:

Steenrod, N. Products of cocycles and extensions of mappings.
Ann. of Math. (2) 48 (1947), 290–320.

A more recent account is given in Chapter 14 of the book Cohomology operations and applications in homotopy theory by Mosher and Tangora.
The result is as follows:

Theorem (Steenrod): Let $X$ be a complex of dimension $n+1$, where $n \geq 3$. Then there is a bijection
$$
[X, S^n] \cong H^n(X; \Z) \times \operatorname{Coker} \phi,
$$
where $\phi$ is the following composition:
$$
H^{n-1}(X; \Z) \xrightarrow{\mod 2} H^{n-1}(X; \Z_2) 
\xrightarrow{ \Sq^2 } H^{n+1}(X; \Z_2)
$$

The idea of the proof given in Mosher-Tangora is to work out the first two stages of a Postnikov tower for $S^n$.
The first stage is $K(\Z,n)$, and the second stage is obtained by killing a map
$$
K(\Z,n) \to K(\Z_2, n+2)
$$
that represents the operation $\Sq^2 \circ \rho$,
where $\rho$ is reduction mod $2$.

Computations for $X = \R P^{n+1}$
To deduce the answer for $X = \R P^{n+1}$, one needs to work out the map $\phi$.
I could not find a reference for the end result.
Hopefully, someone can check that I didn't make any mistakes in the computations.
The computation splits into two cases:
$n$ is even
This case is easy: we have $H^{n-1}(\R P^{n+1}; \Z) = 0$, hence
$$
[\R P^{n+1}, S^n] 
\cong H^{n}(\R P^{n+1}; \Z) \times H^{n+1}(\R P^{n+1}; \Z_2) 
\cong \Z_2 \times \Z_2
$$
$n$ is odd
For $n$ odd, we have $H^{n-1}(\R P^{n+1}; \Z) \cong \Z_2$.
Moreover, by looking at the exact sequence induced by the exact sequence of coefficients
$$
0 \to \Z \xrightarrow{\times 2} \Z \xrightarrow{\mod 2} \Z_2 \to 0,
$$
one sees that the reduction map
$H^{n-1}(\R P^{n+1}; \Z) \to H^{n-1}(\R P^{n+1}; \Z_2)$
is an isomorphism.
It remains to figure out $\Sq^2$ on $H^{n-1}$.
The computation is similar to the case of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ which is worked out in this answer.
Let $x \in H^1(\R P^{n+1}; \Z_2)$ be the generator.
Then $\Sq(x) = x + x^2$. Since $\Sq$ is a map of rings, we have
$$
\Sq(x^k)= \Sq(x)^k = (x+x^2)^k = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (x^2)^j x^{k-j}
=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} x^{k+j}.
$$
Here, the binomial coefficients are reduced mod $2$.
Now $\Sq^2$ corresponds to the term $j=2$ in the last sum, hence
$$
\Sq^2 x^k = \binom{k}{2} x^{k+2}.
$$
Now $\binom{k}{2}$ is even when $k =0,1$ mod $4$ and odd when $k = 2,3$ mod $4$.
Hence we conclude
$$
\Sq^2 x^k = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } k =0,1 \mod 4 \\
x^{k+2} &\text{if } k= 2,3 \mod 4
\end{cases}
$$
The case we are interested in is $k = n-1$ where $n$ is odd, so we obtain:
$$
\Sq^2 x^{n-1} = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } n = 1 \mod 4 \\
x^{n+1} &\text{if } n = 3 \mod 4.
\end{cases}
$$
Putting this all together, and assuming my computations are correct, we conclude:
$$
[ \R P^{n+1}, S^n ] \cong
\begin{cases}
\Z_2 &\text{if } n = 1 \mod 4, \\
0    &\text{if } n = 3 \mod 4.
\end{cases}
$$

(This comment is just to confirm that I've checked the computation and it looks all good to me.)

For a published reference, see West, "Some Cohomotopy of Projective Space", theorem 4.2.

@JHF Thanks for the reference! The computations in the paper seem much closer to what the OP had in mind, so perhaps you can consider posting this as an answer.

I think the calculations are actually quite similar; for instance, the computation of the Steenrod square you did is exactly the same as the one found in the proof of lemma 6.4 of that paper.

Yes, it seems to amount to the same in the end. But what I meant is that the computation proceeds by analyzing the same cofiber sequence that OP was considering (so comparing $\mathbb{R}P^{n+1}$ to spheres), rather than using a Postnikov truncation of the codomain $S^n$.
